# Android resourse folders swXXXdp for 5 inch phones

Tags: android

I want to distinguish phones with ~5 inch and higher displays from 4 inch 480x800 in my res/values folder

How can I differentiate ~5 inch displays?
I should probably use this trick, but what should got instead of XXX?

```
values-swXXXdp?
```

Especially I am trying to differentiate Galaxy S 3 and Galaxy S 4 from others. What should I consider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S3:

```
DPI: 306 
RES: 1280x720
Screen: 4.8"

720 / (306/160) = 720 / 1.9125 = 376.47 dp
```

S4:

```
DPI: 441 
RES: 1920x1080
Screen: 5.0"

1080 / (441/160) = 1080 / 2.75625 = 391.8367 dp
```

So basically there is a very small difference between S3 and S4. But if you want to distinguish layouts for these devices, use **sw376dp** for **S3** and **sw390dp** for **S4**. But make a note that other 5" phones could be different.